# How to classify a string that belongs to a particular area using java?

Tags: java, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-processing, information-retrieval

**A short intro** 
I had extracted a bunch of text from set of PDF files.. Those text are title of the document..

My objective is to classify the titles based on the terms appearing on it. That is if the title contains `Car` then it must be classified as `automobile`.

**Example for my objective**

Imagine the following titles:

> 1) DISTRIBUTED MESH NETWORK 
>      2) MONITORING A SELF-CONTAINED SERVER RACK SYSTEM 
>   3)SIDE PANEL FOR AN AUTOMOBILE 
>   4) LOCATION-BASED VEHICLE MESSAGING SYSTEM

Now , the above mentioned title have to classified as

> 1st title contains term Network , So classify as Networking 
>   2nd title contains term Server, So classify as Networking 
>   3rd title contains term automobile, So classify as automobile 
>   4th title contains term vehicle , so classify as automobile

This is what I need .

**My Works**

To achieve my objective I created a index of terms in text files  for each category and matched it with a title .. if it contains a word in text files , then title get classified.

For example

`Automobile.txt` have  `car , gear , wheel , clutch`. 
`networking.txt` have `server,IP Address,TCP , RIP`

This is the Algorithm:

```
String Classify (String title)
{
 String area;
 if (compareWordsFrom ("Automobile.txt",title) == true ) area = "Auto";
 if (compareWordsFrom ("Netoworking.txt",title) == true ) area = "Networking";
 if (compareWordsFrom ("metels.txt",title) == true ) area = "Metallurgy";
 return area;
}
```

**My Problem** 
My problem is , it is very difficult to find related words to build the index. That is , the field automobile have 1000 of related terms which difficult to find.

To be precise , building index of terms manually is a heart-breaking process.

**My Need** 
I need an automated way for my work . Do Natural Language Processing  techniques able to  do  it. ? OR I is there is an ready-made library available ?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet

> WordNet is a lexical database for the English language. It groups
>   English words into sets of synonyms called synsets, provides short,
>   general definitions, and records the various semantic relations
>   between these synonym sets. The purpose is twofold: to produce a
>   combination of dictionary and thesaurus that is more intuitively
>   usable, and to support automatic text analysis and artificial
>   intelligence applications. The database and software tools have been
>   released under a BSD style license and can be downloaded and used
>   freely. The database can also be browsed online.

WordNet: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) if you haven't done yet.

Comment: I know about Lucene , but it is only for text search , how it tag parts of speech ?